# Magento configswatches Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object

Tags: magento

i am using magento  1.9.1.0 when in admin i goto **admin >catalog > configurable swatches**

i get below error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\mournewcs3\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Form.php on line 463
```

My magento version was updated from 1.9 to 1.9.1.0

i could not figure out how to fix it , based on some online research 
when i comment below text from file
**"app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/etc/system.xml"**

it works fine

commented text :

```
                <swatch_attributes translate="label">
                    <label>Product Attributes to Show as Swatches in Product Detail</label>
                    <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                    <source_model>configurableswatches/system_config_source_catalog_product_configattribute</source_model>
                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                </swatch_attributes>
                <product_list_attribute translate="label">
                    <label>Product Attribute to Use for Swatches in Product Listing</label>
                    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                    <source_model>configurableswatches/system_config_source_catalog_product_configattribute_select</source_model>
                    <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                </product_list_attribute>
```